# Update Sharepoint Online Hub site global navigation link

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can someone let me know how i can update/delete the global navigation link on my sharepoint online hub site?

It was created by someone else who is not with company anymore and i don't find a way to deal with it.
I tried to read the navigation link but it just returns as 1. I dont find any option in site settings as well to check this.

**$TopNavs = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Select-Object Title,Url, Id**[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings-> Hub site settings, choose "Hidden in navigation". As the below picture shows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the screenshot. Wondering how did i miss this without checking the Site Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the  **Set-NavigationNode**,  refer to the below sample code:

```
$navigationNodes = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location $Location 

 foreach($navigationNode in $navigationNodes)
   {

    $node = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id $navigationNode.Id

 Set-NavigationNode $node

   }

  Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Reference:

For details refer to the below article:

[Update SharePoint Navigation After Site Rename](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mattipaukkonen.com/2019/11/29/update-sharepoint-navigation-after-site-rename/amp/)

Comment: When i run below command i don't get result                                           
       $navigationNodes = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location "TopNavigationBar"

Comment: I need to update/delete which is highlighted in the image. Not the ones beside logo(Home,Documents, Site Contents..